# Bootstrap Columns- If one col has margin-bottom then it applies to other col, why?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a page using Bootstrap classes. I came across a concern that I have 2 column layout. One col(col-md-6) has content basically Address and another content has an Image.

As Address in HTML comes with some predefined properties example - margin-bottom: 20px. This margin also come in other col which is not required.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <p>CONTACT:</p>
    <address style="font-size: 16px; font-weight: 600; line-height: 1.7;"><strong><a href="mailto:FaceGard@Saint-Gobain.com">akanksha@gmail.com</a></strong><br><span><img alt="" src="/sites/grindwellnorton.coin/files/phone.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right:10px;">+91 -------</span><br><span><img alt="" src="/sites/grindwellnorton.coin/files/watsapp.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; margin-right:10px;">+91 -----</span></address>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><img alt="" src="/sites/grindwellnorton.coin/files/footer.png" style="float:right;"></div>
</div>
```

I don't need the margin to be applied to the image. I want the Image to be at the bottom, should touched down to the blue bar. How will I get that?

[image]

[This is the final output I want. The image to be at the bottom of the div. For now I have managed it by giving margin-top: 29px;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1PjD.png)

Comment: Please try adding class "align-bottom" to `<div class="row">`, did it worked?

Comment: The problem that you are having is the columns aren't the same height, and the tallest one pushes down the row below it giving the impression of a random margin. If you are using Bootstrap 4, each column is flex so they are the same height.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap3 here @MisirJafarov

Comment: So how can I avoid this random margin on the other side of the column. @imvain2

Comment: So you want to join both those images? Right. Then make that above image part of the blue bar using the `:before`, `:after`.

Comment: Yes , I want the image "<div class="col-md-6"><img alt="" src="/sites/grindwellnorton.coin/files/footer.png" style="float:right;"></div>" To be be at the bottom of the div.